# Require a modified gem source code

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

I am trying to `require` a gem source code that I've downloaded and modified. The `require` works for the main file, but the main file `require` other files (classes and modules) and unfortunately, these classes and modules are loaded from the previously installed gem (via `gem` command) and not the locally modified ones.

I am doing a `require './lib/foo'`, any idea to tell the require to load only local files?

EDITED: My `require './lib/foo'` is working. foo is the local version I want. But foo does other requires, and theses requires point to the files of the gem installed (which I don't want as I am trying to correct stuff inside).

Comment: Are your modifications generic and match to the quality of current gem? If so, in addition to any answers you get for immediate use, you could make a pull request on github, and then use the gem as normal when your changes are published.

Comment: Yeah, it's the plan. I just want to be able to test the gem on IRB or a test script before pushing my changes.

Answer (score 2):

uninstall the original gem from system by command

```
  gem uninstall some_gem
```

then go the root of downloaded source code and build your own gem from modified source with command

```
  gem build some_gem.gemspec
```

the install the gem by specifying the generated source file name.

```
  gem install some_gem-version
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to add a `Gemfile` to your project, and set the `source` on the gem(s) you want to customize.

Comment: I see, can you be more explicit? I am actually inside the gem code.

Comment: In your Gemfile, include the line: `gem 'foo', :path => '/home/myDir/foo'`.

Answer (score 0):

Under Ruby 2.0, you can use `__dir__`. So:

```
require "#{__dir__}/lib/foo"
```

will require your local `foo.rb` file and not the `foo.rb` you have in a different directory.

Also, it is better not use the same name as the original gem. You should change the filename to something else.

Comment: Actually, my require './lib/foo' is working. The other issue come from  foo that is requiring other files.

Comment: Thats' strange. `require` should not be able to expand the file name unless you have some strange library working.

Comment: What do you mean? I've: `lib/foo.rb` which contains 'require foo/module1', however it won't load the local version but the installed gem version of `foo/module1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bundler, and you've forked this gem on github or another online git provider, you can modify your Gemfile with the `:git` command (http://bundler.io/v1.3/git.html):

Instead of

`gem some_gem`

you can do

`gem some_gem, :git => 'git://github.com/my_username/my_awesome_fork_of_some_gem.git'`

or even

`gem some_gem, :github => 'my_username/my_awesome_fork_of_some_gem'`